# Alternative to using FSM for implementing round robin

Tags: vhdl, hdl, vhdl-2008

It is easy to implement round robin (A->B->C->A->B->C..) using FSM in VHDL. Is there an alternative to FSM? For some reason, I have a feeling there is a nice and neat implementation without using FSM.

Comment: It depends if you consider a counter to be an FSM. Which it is, though it may not look like one.

Comment: Since FSM is "just" an abstract concept, any implementation I can think of is an FSM. What design that stores a state and changes on input conditions would you not call an FSM?

Answer (score 2):

There are two main goals:

- your code should be readable
- your code should synthesize well

If the FSM fulfills both, then it is the way to go.

If your only transitions are A->B->C->A->..., then the implementation is likely three flip flops in a circle. The FSM with an enumerated type resolves nicely to that because the enumeration will use one-hot encoding by default, and the FSM viewer can be used to inspect this, which is also nice if you want to keep your project readable.